# PHP Convert any kg amount to a readable metric unit

Tags: php, math, numbers, data-conversion, units-of-measurement

I am trying to create a mathematical function (in PHP) that will take a given number of Kg, and convert them to a readable form or better yet, return the unit best suited for that amount. The input will always be kg. Preferably log.

For example:

5 kg = (5) kg

0.5 kg = (500) gm

1000 kg = (1) tonne

0.001 kg = (1) gm

0.0001 kg = (100) mg

I know there is a way to do it using log or log10 functions but I cannot figure it out.

How could it be done?

Comment: prefixes are well defined.. aka "kilo" = 1000, "mega" = 1000000, milli = 1/1000, etc...

Comment: I don’t want to convert to a known unit. I want the function to tell me which is the best unit so I can convert it.

Comment: wait... you don't want to convert it, but then want to know what's the best unit to convert into? A bit contradictionary, isn't it? Anyway, weight base unit is "gramm". On a side note: 1000kg is a "ton" (not "tonne"), and gramm is abbreviated "g", not "gm"

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I believe you have your ton and tonne the wrong way around...

Comment: Are we still talking english? It's "ton", pretty sure.. "Tonne" is german

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I mean it's a standard SI unit so.... Also a `ton` is usually reffered to as an Imperial/English measurement and has nothing to do with `kg`?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz a tonne is a metric ton, 1000 kg, a ton is 2000 lbs. I have to make the differentiation in my app because I have both units available. Here is the link

https://asseteng.com.au/whats-difference-ton-tonne-one-heavier/#:~:text=Both%20are%20a%20unit%20of,tonne%20is%20a%20Metric%20measurement.&text=Each%20has%20a%20different%20weight,grams%20or%20one%20thousand%20kilograms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with it for a while, here is what I came up with

```
    function readableMetric($kg)
    {
        $amt = $kg * pow(1000, 3);
        $s = array('mcg', 'mg', 'gm', 'kg','tonne');
        $e = floor(log10($amt)/log10(1000));
        return [
            "amount" => $amt/pow(1000, $e),
            "unit"   => $s[$e]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Quite nice, but you're now bound to the powers of three. That could be a choice, but here in the Netherlands we have something called an "ons", that is a 100 gram. If something weighs 250 grams we say: "2,5 ons". You cannot add that to this solution. Always keep in might that a shorter solution is not necessarily a better solution. Code needs to be adaptable as well.

Comment: Ons is not an official metric measurement. My question was strictly to convert to metric units. Thank you for the suggestions, however. In my app, I am trying to solve this specific issue. If I were making a more general function, I could include other units and account for those variations.

Comment: Your algorithm works incorrectly on very small and very large numbers like 23489000.

Comment: @jspit the array would need to be expanded to include larger and smaller amounts. Micrograms are a billionth of a KG so there is no need to worry about that end. Higher than tonnes could be handled by never going above an array index of 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work, but I'm sure there are people who can make a much better solution.

```
function outputWeight($kg)
{
  $power = floor(log($kg, 10));    
  switch($power) {
    case 5  :
    case 4  :
    case 3  : $unit = 'ton'; 
              $power = 3;
              break;
    case 2  :
    case 1  :    
    case 0  : $unit = 'kilogram'; 
              $power = 0;
              break;
    case -1 : 
    case -2 : 
    case -3 : $unit = 'gram'; 
              $power = -3;
              break;
    case -4 : 
    case -5 : 
    case -6 : $unit = 'milligram'; 
              $power = -6;
              break;
    default : return 'out of range';
  }
  return ($kg / pow(10, $power)) . ' ' . $unit;
}  

echo outputWeight(0.015) . '<br>';
echo outputWeight(0.15) . '<br>';
echo outputWeight(1.5) . '<br>';
echo outputWeight(15) . '<br>';
echo outputWeight(150) . '<br>';
```

The idea is that you can easily extend the range. This will output

```
15 gram
150 gram
1.5 kilogram
15 kilogram
150 kilogram
```

**I did not thoroughly test this code!**

Comment: Just in case you find a bug... in my defense: 0.0 kg is not a weight. Nor is -1.0 kg.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about using log or log10

Answer (score 1):

The following function internally uses an array with the assignments unit => conversion-factor. This array can easily be expanded or modified to meet your own requirements. A fixed limit of 1000 is used in the function. This means that the output value is always less than 1000, with the exception of tons. With an additional argument which is preset to 2, the number of maximum decimal places can be changed.

```
function scaleKg(float $kg, int $decimalPlaces = 2) : string {
  $scale = [
    'micrograms' => 1.E9,
    'milligram' => 1.E6,
    'gram' => 1.E3,
    'kilogram' => 1,
    'ton' => 1.E-3,
  ];
  foreach($scale as $unit => $factor){
    $mass = $kg * $factor;
    if($mass < 1000) {
      return round($mass,$decimalPlaces).' '.$unit;
    }
  } 
  return round($mass,$decimalPlaces).' '.$unit;
}
```

Some examples:

```
$kg = 1.212345;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //1.21 kilogram

$kg = 455;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //455 kilogram

$kg = 0.0456;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //45.6 gram

$kg = 23456;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //23.46 ton

$kg = 23489000;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //23489 ton

$kg = 167E-6;
echo scaleKg($kg);  //167 milligram
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself agreeing with Kiko that the shortest code isn't always the best or most readable.

Bearing that in mind bringing `log` into it seems like unnecessary complication. So I suggest a condensed version of my original code:

```
function readableMetric($mass)
{
    $units = [
        -3 => "tonne",
         0 => "kg",
         3 => "g",
         6 => "mg",
    ];

    foreach ($units as $x => $unit) {
        if ( ($newMass = $mass * 10 ** $x)  >= 1 ) {
            return "{$newMass} {$unit}";
        }
    }
}
```

- This is more extensible (e.g. you could easily add `centigram`)
- The math is intuitive to most (powers of 10)
- If you really want to `golf` it you can shrink it down to a one liner:

  ```
   function readableMetric($m)
   {
       foreach([-3=>"tonne",0=>"kg",3=>"g",6 =>"mg"] as $x=>$g)if(($n=$m*10**$x)>=1)return"$n $g";
   }
  ```

---

---

## Original Answer

You could just do it with a series of `if / else` statements?

```
$values = [
    5, 0.5, 1000, 0.001, 0.0001
];



function convertmass($mass) : string
{
    if ($mass >= 1000) {
        return ($mass / 1000) . " ton";
    }
    elseif ($mass < 0.001) {
        return ($mass * 1000000) . " mg";
    }
    elseif ($mass < 1) {
        return ($mass * 1000 ) . " g";
    }
    else {
        return $mass . " kg";
    }
}

foreach ($values as $mass) {
    echo convertmass($mass), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
5 kg
500 g
1 ton
1 g
100 mg
```

---

If you want slightly easier/more readable/more user friendly updating to add new measurements in then you can do something like this instead:

```
$values = [
    5, 0.5, 1000, 0.001, 0.0001
];



function convertmass($mass) : string
{

    $massLookup = [
        [ "unit" => "kg",    "min" => 1,        "max" => 1000,    "multiple" => 1],
        [ "unit" => "tonne", "min" => 1000,     "max" => 1000000, "multiple" => 0.001],
        [ "unit" => "g",     "min" => 0.001,    "max" => 1,       "multiple" => 1000],
        [ "unit" => "mg",    "min" => 0.000001, "max" => 0.001,   "multiple" => 1000000],
    ];

    foreach ($massLookup as $unit) {
        if ($mass >= $unit["min"] && $mass < $unit["max"]) {
            return ($mass * $unit["multiple"]) . " {$unit["unit"]}";
        }
    }

    return "Measurement {$mass} kg is out of range";
}

foreach ($values as $mass) {
    echo convertmass($mass), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I already currently have. I was trying to shorten down the function to 2-3 lines using logarithms.

Comment: See my above function called readableMetric. This is what I was looking for -- figured it out using log10 PHP function

Comment: @DeltaTango I see; that's not how I interpreted the question. Still, I have updated the answer with an alternative solution.. Including a one liner if that's your thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by defining a constant array of supported units indexed by the log10 value (start/stop wherever you choose but use every third power w/o skipping any).
Then you just need a little bit of logic to determine which unit to use.

```php
const KG_CONVERT = [
    -15 => 'pg',
    -12 => 'ng',
     -9 => 'µg',
     -6 => 'mg',
     -3 => 'g',
      0 => 'kg',
      3 => 't',
      6 => 'kt',
      9 => 'Mt', 
     12 => 'Gt',
];
function convertKg($kg){
    $p = floor(log10($kg));
    $m = $p % 3;
    if(0 > $p && 0 !== $m)
      $p -= 3; // use next smaller unit 100mg instead of .1g
    
    // snap to one of the supported units
    $i = $p - $m;
    // don't go below pg
    $i = max($i, min(array_keys(KG_CONVERT)));
    // don't go above Gt
    $i = min($i, max(array_keys(KG_CONVERT)));
    
    return $kg/10**$i . KG_CONVERT[$i];
}
```

[See it in action in my sandbox.](https://onlinephp.io?s=fZTdbpswFMevh8Q7nEZeAxUhsGiTpizdxVTlotomTdNu2qmixHwMsJExWdG0x-oL9Ml2bCAhBA2QfX7_43MwPjYfPpZJaRrLJdwwSQU0vBYQ8h2FhArqAGW_eHNhGiQQImhgA3em8cr1RpfvTKhT4oR2Lp0pY2HEp3hCQxjYR_Ng9UbXt51u28Zr27479EdjYA3NE_sURjTGMz4XJpQpaVLT4s-1aZhGyFkl4Xb78Onrlx833753dV74b2FzDfMynjsa32hkLcLivcaX557faS56XGnsCDxNWY-tU3bURmY9tok_I4Li7r1b7VYzjmoWypQz3KlsT4W8jS2SxfYfHExKnHyUcy6snMe-px32WnkK9JDy9UpBGlkeXCPC5SVO7WKDrsLWL0dtsYHVGvBQ1BUFRp8kVEWQ53g-apZKwJUsYmBcguvHGIMPjq0kHpCUgUwoiIDFFHgEVV2WXEi605FVO3LH2VxCzOGR5vw3lCoHSXF2RfBkkXJBCgeKlFn6zD1ktKmsY23s9muGaYJHvqewlYc0GEtSR6f7Xw58BJW1YICLtPS9qysMd2GOtzvYDXckVYv-V-2UiAsahIkF3Q8hqDCWNqo-ZB_kNQVVBcCLhgnvNHeWxfcSh8zcQcG0y3Zn92ymsv8D&v=7.4.33%2C7.0.33%2C8.0.28)